# AudioAttributes FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED and Volume

Tags: java, android, android-studio

quick question as it seems I might have missed something.

I have a media player class with which I want to play a mp3.

I set the attributes thus...

```
 AudioAttributes aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setFlags(FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .build(
 mediaplayer.setAudioAttributes(aa);
```

However, when the track plays it uses the System (Ringer) volume as the master volume control. Not the media volume as I would expect. If I miss out setting the flag...

```
.setFlags(FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
```

It works as expected and uses the media volume. Why does setting the flag above change which volume on the device controls the playback?

Thank you!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue at the moment with our alarm clock app.

Comment: Hello. Let me know if you find an answer... I never did. Basically I just had to live with it in the end so would be very interested if you find a way round it...

Comment: As per its definition, it says "defining a behavior where the audibility of the sound will be ensured by the system". On based on that, my assumption is, it is working with Ringer profile as in specific scenario, app may need to play audio based on profile. For example, if phone is on silent mode, music must not be played at Silent zones. :)

Comment: In my recent experience, it depends A LOT on the device. Some brands choose to associate your MediaPlayer to a volume stream, say "media", while others will link it to "notifications"; what's worse is that in some cases, the user will be unable to silence your player (or even change the volume!!). My advice is that, unless you really need it, you avoid this flag. It is, at best, unreliable and "non-deterministic".