Jetpack Media3 Volume Control Issue on Samsung S24 (Android 14)
I'm currently developing a custom alarm app using the Android Jetpack Media3 library, specifically version 1.4.1. I've noticed that when it comes to controlling the volume of the sound stream, I'm able to adjust the volume on all my available physical devices and emulators - except on my Samsung S24. On this particular device, I'm unable to change the volume in any form, whether through programmatic control or by using the physical volume buttons.
I filled allready a bug report on the Google Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/363916146
This problem is a major blocker for my development, and I'm considering reverting to the legacy MediaPlayer and abandoning Media3 altogether.
Does anyone have any advice or experience with similar issues for volume control on Samsung devices? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Steps to Reproduce:

Run the provided Media3.MediaSessionService example code on a Samsung S24 device.(see https://developer.android.com/media/media3/session/background-playback).

Attempt to adjust the volume using either system volume controls or programmatically within the app (using AudioManager).

Observe that volume adjustments have no effect on the media playback.


Expected Behavior:
Volume adjustments made through system controls or in-app should be reflected in the media playback volume.
Actual Behavior:
Volume adjustments have no impact on the media playback volume on the Samsung S24 device.
Device Information:

Device: Samsung S24
OS: Android 14
One UI Version: 6.1

Additional Information:

The issue is specific to the Samsung S24 device.
The code functions correctly on other tested devices (physical Moto G04s, emulated Pixel 8 API 34 & 35).
Relevant code snippets included highlight volume control and audio attribute setup.
For USAGE_ALARM, there is no volume control shown in the UI for "Alarm clock" on the Samsung S24, while all other devices show this.
PlaybackSessionService.onStartCommand triggers playerBackground.play() and runs as a foreground service (triggered by an alarm broadcast receiver)
Google Clock and Samsung clock apps work on S24 as expected (volume control possible and shown)

Code Snippets (Reduced on non-default settings):
import androidx.media3.common.AudioAttributes as Media3AudioAttributes;

class PlaybackSessionService : MediaSessionService() {

// ... (Relevant parts of the provided code)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Setting audio attributes
        val musicAudioAttributes = Media3AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA) // or C.USAGE_ALARM, depending on use case
            .setContentType(C.AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setAllowedCapturePolicy(C.ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE)
            .setFlags(C.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
            .build()

        playerBackground = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setDeviceVolumeControlEnabled(true)
            .setAudioAttributes(musicAudioAttributes, /* handleAudioFocus= */ false)
            .build()

        // ... (Volume adjustment attempts)

        playerBackground.volume = 0.1f

        if (audioManager.isVolumeFixed()) {
            Log.e("PlaybackService", "Volume is fixed") // not executed
        }

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, // or C.STREAM_ALARM, depending on use case
            (audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) // or C.STREAM_ALARM, depending on use case
                    * defaultAlarmVolumeLevel).toInt(),
            0 //FLAG_SHOW_UI also no effect
        )

        // add session to service explicitly, otherwise notification is not shown
        addSession(mediaSession!!)
    } // end of onCreate
    
    // ...
}


TL;DR
Using the default Media3 example code (MediaSession background play, https://developer.android.com/media/media3/session/background-playback), volume control and setting the volume programmatically does not work as expected on a Samsung S24 device (Android 14, One UI Version 6.1). Volume control functions correctly on other tested devices (physical Moto G04s, emulated Pixel 8 API 34 & 35).

it seems to be related to .setFlags(C.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855786/audioattributes-flag-audibility-enforced-and-volume
